# Recover TFS 2012 after server or PC crash

Tags: backup, visual-studio-2010, team-foundation-server

I am using Team foundation server 2012.I do take backup of all TFS databases regularly. So now in case of disaster recovery(in case full machine gets crash) how can i use this backup to recover TFS and all collection etc.
I want easy and the best approach .

I have seen so many articles in microsoft website but nothing is really so helpful and difficult to understand. So please suggest a better tutorial or procedure to do it

Comment: How do you make the 'full backups' ? Which software do you use? To which medium?

Comment: I do backup of sql database(TFS related database) using backup option of sql server